# Oracle `missing expression` error when selecting system date and other columns

Tags: sql, oracle, plsql

I've worked only with SQL Server up until now, this is my first time working with Oracle and I can't figure this out.

I want to select all the data that is accessible from a view and also I want to select the current system date. I've tried to run this set of queries but nothing is returned.

```
SELECT
    (SELECT SYSDATE FROM DUAL),
    *
FROM myView;
```

I've noticed that `missing expression` is thrown, but I can't understand (don't know) what's incorrect about my query.

**Update:**

This IS the entire query I'm trying to run, nothing fancy.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

There's no need for a sub-query and you need to alias the object you're selecting from:

```
select sysdate, a.* from myview a
```

If your sub-query is more complex you still need to do this:

```
select ( select sysdate from dual ), a.* from myview a
```

If you're returning a single row then a CROSS JOIN would be more appropriate:

```
select dt, a.*
  from myview a
 cross join ( select sysdate as dt from dual )
```

Comment: Perfect, this is just what I was looking for. Thanks! Although I can't understand why aliases are required if the `select sysdate` statement is surrounded by brackets. But maybe I'm just used to SQL Server..

Comment: @RaduGheorghiu that's because Oracle doesn't allow you do just put in a `*` when mixed with another expression - must explicitly refer to the source - in terms of an alias & the columns, in this case a `*` to indicate what you want to fetch.